# Attempt to connect to URL using okhttpClient to grab a Json

Tags: android, json, tomcat

I'm trying to get a Json file to my Android app. I'm using Tomcat this is part of my code:

```
final String servidor = "10.0.2.2:8080/ProjetoTCC";
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPasswordU;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPasswordU = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        requester = new MoradorRequester();

        if(requester.isConnected(LoginActivity.this)) {
            intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);

            try {
                morador = requester.get("http://" + servidor + "/ValidacaoLoginAndroid.json", mEmail, mPasswordU);


                        intent.putExtra("MORADOR", morador);
                        if(morador.getValidacao() == true){
                        startActivity(intent);}

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Rede indisponível!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Here I call the method MoradorRequester() that try to connect and get the Json object. Here is the Moredor Requester():

```
    try {
        JSONArray root = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
        JSONObject item = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++ ) {
            item = (JSONObject) root.get(i);

            morador.setNome(item.getString("nome_completo"));
            morador.setDataNascimento(item.getString("data_nascimento"));
            morador.setnApartamento(item.getInt("n_apartamento"));
            morador.setEmail(item.getString("email"));
            morador.setValidacao((Boolean) item.get("validacao"));

        }

    } catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
finally {
    if(morador == null)
        morador.setDataNascimento("10/10/2010");
        morador.setEmail("email");
        morador.setnApartamento(0);
        morador.setNome("Sem Nome");
        morador.setDataNascimento("10/10/2010");
        morador.setValidacao(true);
}
```

The Requester is not able to grab the Json and I always receive the default user that I created on the finally.

I tried to debug and I received an error when the Android run the "String jsonStr = response.body().string();" the error is the following:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=http://10.0.2.2:8080/ProjetoTCC/ValidacaoLoginAndroid.json}
```

Also, I received the following error on Android monitor:

```
09-25 19:24:01.080 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
09-25 19:24:01.115 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
09-25 19:24:01.115 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
09-25 19:24:01.115 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
09-25 19:24:01.115 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at network.MoradorRequester.get(MoradorRequester.java:52)
09-25 19:24:01.117 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at com.example.arthurf.tcc.app.Controller.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:220)
09-25 19:24:01.117 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at com.example.arthurf.tcc.app.Controller.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:201)
09-25 19:24:01.117 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
09-25 19:24:01.117 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-25 19:24:01.117 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
09-25 19:24:01.117 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
09-25 19:24:01.117 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
09-25 19:24:01.117 2414-2977/com.example.arthurf.tcc.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I already tested the Json and it seems to be working fine, returning what I need, I believe that is some issue in the connection between the Android and the Server.

If you want, you can check my code on GitHub:

https://github.com/ArthurFranchetto/TCCTest1.git

Have I missed something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try RETROFIT 1.9 ?

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

RETROFIT is a REST client API for Android that is far far way much more easy to use than use only OKHTTP and JsonObjects...

The 1.9 version make automatic Json parsing using GSON and OKHTTP and you just need use a callback to get the data as your bean object.

This project you can use as guide to develop your app:

https://github.com/elcioabrahao/PDV_2016

[]'s